# Sphinx INTERNAL ERROR: incoming-schema mismatch

Tags: php, sphinx

I am trying to get this index to work:

```
sql_query               = \

SELECT bo.es_id, bo.es_id as id, mem.es_country, es_uid, bo.es_featured 
as es_featured,
**bo.es_reverse_featured**, mem.es_signup_status as es_signup_status, mem.es_memtype as es_memtype, es_title, es_keywords, bo.tempdate, bo.es_postedon, bo.es_reverse_featured, bo.es_viewed, mem.es_reverse_memtype \
                FROM ephpb2b_offers_buy bo INNER JOIN ephpb2b_members mem ON bo.es_uid=mem.es_id \
        Where bo.es_featured IN (0,1)

sql_attr_uint = id
sql_attr_uint = es_signup_status
sql_attr_uint = es_memtype
sql_attr_uint = es_reverse_memtype
sql_attr_uint = es_country
sql_attr_uint = es_uid
sql_attr_timestamp = es_postedon
sql_attr_timestamp = tempdate
**sql_attr_uint = es_reverse_featured**
sql_attr_uint = es_viewed
sql_attr_uint = es_featured
```

It's giving me error:

```
    index tradeban_b2bdb_bo_relevent: INTERNAL ERROR: incoming-schema mismatch
(in=uint es_reverse_featured:32@288, my=uint es_reverse_featured:32@128)
```

I tried googling and came up with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665449/sphinx-daemon-returned-error-index-product-core-internal-error-incoming-schem). But it's about Ruby and thinking-sphinx and  and I am using php. What does this error mean and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from the few responses, some other questions and [the sourcecode](http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/sphinx.cpp): You have either

- created multiple indexes for the same column
- or, what seems likelier to me here, is that you also have an index called `es_reverse_featured`. Since you are trying to select a same-named column inside of your query, these clash.

Try the following query instead, which renames your column to `es_reverse_featured_2`:

```
SELECT bo.es_id, bo.es_id as id, mem.es_country, es_uid,
 bo.es_featured AS es_featured,
 bo.es_reverse_featured AS es_reverse_featured_2,
 mem.es_signup_status AS es_signup_status, mem.es_memtype as es_memtype, es_title,
 es_keywords, bo.tempdate, bo.es_postedon, bo.es_reverse_featured, bo.es_viewed,
 mem.es_reverse_memtype
FROM ephpb2b_offers_buy bo
INNER JOIN ephpb2b_members mem ON bo.es_uid=mem.es_id
Where bo.es_featured IN (0,1)
```

Comment: thank you @GhostGambler. I solved my issue by selecting reverse_featured just once. Apparently I was selecting it twice in my select statement.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help SO fellows.

I found that I was selecting es_reverse_featured twice in my select statement:

`Select es_reverse_featured, other_field1, other_field2, es_reverse_featured from table1`.

I removed the other entry and issue was resolved.